# Is there any Open Source Office Chat Messenger?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, software-rec, lan, chat

I am looking for an open source instant chat messenger for Office purposes.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Office purpose"?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Remember that depending on your country, your employer, and your employment contract, use of office internet for private chats might get you fired.

Comment: I want to use in Office only and it should connect to office LAN only. I need for Windows XP, 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/); as far as I know it's the go-to open source option.

It supports both server-based messaging as well as the serverless Bonjour protocol, so if you don't need or want to set up an IM server, Pidgin will still work.

Answer (score 2):

In our company we use [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/), it's opensource works fine.

This is only a solution if you're a network administrator and it's a company or department wide solution you need.

Answer (score 0):

http://psi-im.org/

It's free LAN Messenger with many facilities available. Check this out. Also it has web management console for users, groups etc.,